# Apache2 vhost configuration problem

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualization, configuration, host

What I'd like apache to do is match every request for example.com and redirect to www.example.com. Any other hosts sent by a browser that are not on this domain should return a 404.

Here are my two vhosts:

example.com:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

000-default:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

What actually happens is that "www.example.com" is beeing served as it should, a host header of "test" is beeing 404'd as it should, while "example.com" is beeing 404'd, and it shouldn't.

It's like apache matches "www" to the ServerName directive, but the ServerAlias is beeing ignored, and a subdomain of "sub" matches the default vhost instead.

Comment: If I remove the 000-default vhost apache will correctly forward non-www subdomain requests to www, but will also serve any junk host with the example.com vhost instead of returning the 404 from the 000-default one

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Will handle fixing your www/non-www stuff.

Then for any other hosts, just point your default vhost to some empty documentroot (or some script that handles whatever custom 404 you want.

Comment: This will cause a redirect loop. Furthermore, it will not forward the requests to the www domain as the rewrite rule does, but just blindly redirect to the www domain.

Comment: Sorry dude, you're wrong on both counts.  Assuming there is another vhost for www.example.com (which does not redirect), there will be no loop.  and example.com/asdf/123 will be redirected to www.example.com/asdf/123.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add example.com to your ServerAlias line:

```
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
```

And then rewrite your RewriteCond to be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

...because I don't think you need that first %{HTTP_HOST} line.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

I get the redirect from non-www to www, but example.com alone returns a 404